# DRF - Nested Reverse Relation Serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I create a serializer that returns all the results for a `family`, with ALL the reverse relationships?

```
         Family
           |
    +------+------+
    |             |
 Student    EmergencyContact
    |
   Fee
```

e.g.

```
{family: [{id: 1,
          student_set: [{id: 1, name: "bob Jones", fee_set: [{"Maths Fee": 3,  "English Fee": 5}}],
                        {id: 2, name: "Mike Jones", fee_set: [{"English Fee": 5}}],
          emergency_contact_set: [{id: 1, name:"Joe"}, {id: 2, name: "Mike"}]
         ]
}
```

I can get a **single** nested level of data using `<model>_set` in the fields, e.g. `student_set, emergency_contact_set`, but **not** deep nested, (the `fee_set`).

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = StudentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)  # does nothing
    class Meta:
          model = Family
          fields = ["id",
                    "name", 
                    "student", # returns nothing
                    "student_set" # only returns the students WITHOUT the fees
                   ]
```

The output (does not have `fees`):

```
{family: [{id: 1,
          student_set: [{id: 1, name: "bob Jones"}],
                        {id: 2, name: "Mike Jones"}],
          emergency_contact_set: [{id: 1, name:"Joe"}, {id: 2, name: "Mike"}],
         ]
}
```

Ideally I would like to use a `StudentSerializer` and `EmergencyContactSerializer` inside `Family`, to get the nested sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `source` kwarg in the `XXXXSerializer`, eg. `source="<field>_set"` (or rename the `related_field` in the model, and use that as the `source`).

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    student = StudentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source="student_set") 
    ...

    class Meta:
        ...
```

and the field `student` will be available for use by the `StudentSerializer`

See:
https://riptutorial.com/django-rest-framework/example/30725/getting-list-of-all-related-children-objects-in-parent-s-serializer